# how to display floating window without permission?

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-permissions, android-windowmanager

i tried to display floating window in android 10 / Core M01 using WindowManger, but i am not able to get "Display over apps" permission:-
[image]
i tried to use "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST" and "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY" and "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE", and nothing work for me.
i get the error:"BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?" when i use TYPE_TOAST and the error of the permission is the other types.
this app works fine without getting the permission: [Mouse Cursor Touchpad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alwys.visiblemosue), and many apps like universal Copy, Mobizen..etc
how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it using **WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY**
in Accessibility Service

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
Context ctx=(Context)this;
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams wLP = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
wLP.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY;
//....etc
}
}
```